# How to click programmatically on a ListViewHeader?

Tags: vb.net, listview, events

I want click programmatically on a ListViewColumnHeader. Something like:

```
RaiseEvent lsvExample.ColumnClick()
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want click programmitically on a ListViewColumnHeader.

Comment: no, you have decided that is *how* to do something.  *what* do want to happen as a result of your fake click?

Comment: When I click on the Header "something" (Sorting) will happen started from the ListView.    (Now: When I click manual all works fine.)  (So, don't care "what happen after")

Comment: Yes,i know. I implentent my own sort-method. All works fine, when i click manually on the header of the listview.     But now, I want to Start the sorting by program. (-> programmitically click on the header)

Comment: then just call/invoke your sorter passing args like ColumnIndex and SortOrder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
lsvExample.ListViewItemSorter = New MyListViewItemStringComparerASC(0)
lsvExample.Sort()
```

This is not a solution for my click-problem. But so I can start the sort-algorithm by program.